# Jeykyll, what is the difference between {%- do-someting -%} and {% do-someting %}?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In the `Jeykll` in documentation to [Liquid](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/) I found the notation `{% … %}` but in some plugins or example code snippets I saw also `{%- … -%}` (with a dash after and before percentage symbol). What is the right usage?

- a) {%- include header.html -%}
- b) {% include header.html %}

Or is it even dependent from the command / option / function which I am using inside the block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dashes give you the ability to control the whitespace around your tags. This often isn’t necessary for HTML generation, but can come in handy for certain uses in pre-formatted text. Or, if you are just picky about what your final HTML looks like ;)

Check out the docs here: https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/whitespace/